# Asymptote figures don't appear with vimtex

Tags: asymptote, vim

I'm trying use the asymptote package with vimtex, it's the first time I try it. When I try to compile, the figure doesn't appear at all in the pdf. This is an example code I found to test:

```
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote} % I've also tried without [inline] but I get the same results
...
\begin{asy}
    settings.outformat = "pdf";
    defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
    label("Hello world!");
\end{asy}
```

The only warning I get is

```
Package asymptote Warning: file `***-1.pdf' not found on input line 30.
```

The `myfile-*.asy` files do appear in the folder.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1113) in the vimtex github where they suggest using a latexmkrc file with

```
sub asy {return system("asy \"$_[0]\"");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

I tried putting this file in the folder I'm working on but it makes the vimtex compilation fail inmediately.

Update:

Running `asy myfile-1.asy` in the terminal returns this error:

```
no matching variable 'byteinv'
no matching variable '_schur'
```

To fix this I've manually updated to 2.85, because was using the MiKTeX version 2.81 which didn't work properly. Now it works if I run `asy myfile-1.asy` manually, but vimtex doesn't do it automatically.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Does your compilation generate `myfile-*.asy` type files in the working directory? Does latexmk generate any other `myfile-*` files with a different extension? What does running `which asy` in a terminal give you?

Comment: @DaiBowen `myfile-*.asy` do generate in the folder, nothing else besides the usual `.log`, `.out`, etc. Running `which asy` returns "which" isn't recognized as a command. I tried in Windows cmd, not sure if that's the right place

Comment: Ah, Windows (I'm assuming you're not using WSL then), can you try `Get-Command asy` in Windows PowerShell (not command prompt), it should give one hit, matching `Get-Command pdflatex`? If that looks good, try running `asy myfile-*.asy` from the prompt after navigating to your working directory and see what it does.

Comment: @DaiBowen The `Get-Command` s look good, running `asy myfile-*.asy` returns what look like 3 errors: `no matching variable 'byteinv'` and `no matching variable '_schur'` twice. I've searched and found [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/909cd01735/) discussion with the same problem, it looks like the problem is in the MiKTeX asy version, which is also my case. I'll try the solution in the link and I'll update the question when I can.

Comment: Ah, that's beyond me, but sounds like you just need to replace the MiKTeX installed asymptote and then as long as you can get it on your path to run `asy myfile-*.asy` then latexmk/vimtex should just work

Comment: I suggest you one way out of such trouble: come http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ to run any `asy` code, for example,
`label("Hello world!");` then download pdf figre and use `\inclugraphics' in your LaTeX document.

Comment: @DaiBowen It worked, now asymptote works but vimtex still doesn't compile automatically.

Comment: @DavidCA thanks for the update, I assume `latexmk myfile` also doesn't do the compilation, I'll try see if I can get the `latexmkrc` working.

Comment: @DaiBowen nevermind, it works now! Maybe restarting my PC did something. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, if it's working reliably maybe you could add a self-answer about the Asymptote/MiKTeX issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `.asy` files can't compile because apparently the MiKTeX distribution of Asymptote doesn't have compatible files and executable, as pointed out [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/909cd01735/#b805). Instead, download and install Asymptote from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/asymptote/) and copy the files from `C:\Program Files\Asymptote` (not sure if you need all the files but it works for me) into the same directory as the incompatible version (`C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64` in my case) (there might be another way to use the correct executable without copying the files, but that's beyond my knowledge). I think you also need to rename the `asy.exe` file you copied to `miktex-asy.exe`.

Now you can compile the `.asy` files by executing them with the Asymptote program or in a terminal with `asy myfile-*.asy`.

Vimtex uses latexmk by default. In order to automatically compile the `myfile-*.asy` files when compiling with vimtex, you need to add a `.latexmkrc` file in the directory you're working on with the following:

```
sub asy {return system("asy \"$_[0]\"");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

Comment: Best should be to get the `C:\Program Files\Asymptote` exe on path (might be automatic and just require a restart or be an install option), and then uninstall asymptote within MiKTeX.